# Is it possible to use metric "k" notations in excel?

Tags: vba, excel, formatting

Is it possible to work in Excel with some metric suffix notation:
If I write 1000, the cell shows `1k`. if I write 1000000 the cell shows `1M`.

I made two functions to make a workaround but maybe there's a more suitable solution.

```
Function lecI(cadena) As Double
    u = Right(cadena, 1)
    If u = "k" Then
        mult = 1000
    ElseIf u = "M" Then
        mult = 1000000
    ElseIf u = "m" Then
        mult = 0.001
    End If
    lecI = Val(Left(cadena, Len(cadena) - 1)) * mult
End Function

Function wriI(num) As String
    If num > 1000000 Then 'M
        wriI = Str(Round(num / 1000000, 2)) & "M"
    ElseIf num > 1000 Then 'k
        wriI = Str(Round(num / 1000, 1)) & "k"
    ElseIf num < 0.01 Then 'm
        wriI = Str(Round(num * 1000, 1)) & "m"
    Else: wriI = Str(num)
    End If
```

Comment: see this http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/custom-number-format.html

Comment: Once OP creates strings out of the perfectly fine numbers he could at least format them nicely to create functional strings... `Format(num,"#,##0")`. Or he could use the `Range.NumberFormat` method after to at least have funcitonal numbers. OFF/Rant: "This is called the *mosqear*, it's neither quite a mosquito nor a bear." /Hungarian proverb/

Comment: @Vasily, I worked your link into a general helper which uses conditional formatting to decide which thousands group to put the number into.  Always good to think of using Number Format first before losing the cell value as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [link by @Vasily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30544932/is-it-possible-to-use-metric-k-notations-in-excel/30577371#comment49162998_30544932), you can get the desired outcome using only Conditional Formatting.  This is nice because it means that all of **your values are stored as Numbers and not Text and math works like normal**.

Overall steps:

- Create a new conditional formatting for each block of 1000 that applies the number format for that block
- Add the largest condition at the top so it formats first
- Rinse and repeat to get all the ones you want

**Conditional formatting** used to style column `C` which is just random data at different powers of ten.  It is the same number as column `D` just styled differently.

[image: conditional setup]

**Number formats**, are pretty easy since they are the same as [that link, see Large Numbers section](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/custom-number-format.html).

- ones = `0 " "`
- thousands = `0, " k"`
- millions = `0,, " M"`
- and so on for however many you want

**Automation**, if you don't want to click and type all day, here is some VBA that will create all the conditional formatting for you (for current `Selection`).  This example goes out to billions.  Keep adding powers of 3 by extending the `Array` with more entries.

```
Sub CreateConditionalsForFormatting()

    'add these in as powers of 3, starting at 1 = 10^0
    Dim arr_markers As Variant
    arr_markers = Array("", "k", "M", "B")

    For i = UBound(arr_markers) To 0 Step -1

        With Selection.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlGreaterEqual, 10 ^ (3 * i))
            .NumberFormat = "0" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Rept(",", i) & " "" " & arr_markers(i) & """"
            .StopIfTrue = False
        End With

    Next

End Sub
```

I change the `StopIfTrue` value so that this does not break other conditional formatting that might exist.  If the largest condition is at the top (added first) then the `NumberFormat` from that one holds.  By default, these are created with `StopIfTrue = True`.  This is a moot point if you do not have any other conditional formatting on these cells.